# Getting Error : '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in python

Tags: python

In Python3 i'm Facing the issue,(in if day=="monday" line) please help me to resolve it,the question is divided into two parts

```
print("Enter the Day")
    day=input()
    print("Enter the age")
    age=input()
    if day=="Monday":
        if age>10:
            print("Wow")
        else:
            print("Bad")
    elif day=="Tuesday":
        print("Average")
    elif day=="Wednesday":
        print=("Good")
    elif day=="Thursday":
        print("better")
    elif day=="Friday":
        print("Well")
    elif day=="Sunday":
        print("So Far So Good")
    else:
        print("Bad Luck")
```

And When I'm Replacing (>) mark with (==),Then getting output "Bad"

```
print("Enter the Day")
day=input()
print("Enter the age")
age=input()
if day=="Monday":
    if age==10:
        print("Wow")
    else:
        print("Bad")
elif day=="Tuesday":
    print("Average")
elif day=="Wednesday":
    print=("Good")
elif day=="Thursday":
    print("better")
elif day=="Friday":
    print("Well")
elif day=="Sunday":
    print("So Far So Good")
else:
    print("Bad Luck")
```

Please Help

Comment: I recommend you take some time to [read the excellent Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/). For example [this reference about the `input` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string type. You will need to use the following instead.

```
age = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
age=input()
```

so age is a string. You can't compare string to int as says the error message, you've got to convert it to an int:

```
raw_age = input()
age = int(raw_age)
```

Comment: age = int(input) or age = int(input())?

Comment: int(raw_age) actually, but thanks for noticing there was a mistake